# Does waitid consume SIGCHLD?

Tags: c, signals, posix

Do `waitid`/`waitpid` consume any pending `SIGCHLD`?

E.g., if one thread calls `waitid` while another one calls `sigwaitinfo` or reads from `signalfd`, can I assume that both calls return correct data when the child process terminates?

Comment: No.  Assume one per customer.

Answer (score 2):

Found https://lkml.org/lkml/2009/1/10/181 :

> That notification only tells us that *at least one* process has died;
>      SIGCHLD may only be pending once at a time.  If further children die
>      before we clear the signal, nothing will happen.
>   ...
>      Because it only tells us that *at least one* process has died, we have
>      to call waitpid() repeatedly until we have exhausted the wait queue.
>
> ~~Calling waitpid() does not clear the pending signal.~~

Мanpages do not mention "wait queue", but it explains a few things.

Comment: Right, there are 2 separate things going on here.  When children die - depending on some settings - a signal is sent to the parent but, SIGCHLD being a standard signal, multiple instances aren't queued.  But multiple process entries from the dead children do build up in the process table.  That's why waitpid is normally called in a loop.  So if one thread is eating PT entries with waitpid and a second thread processes the signal some time later is the signal data "correct"?  I suppose that depends on what you mean by correct. The signal is stale and the normal flow of stimulus/response

Comment: is broken.  I see where the question is useful from cautionary stand point but it is unclear to me if you are trying to go somewhere else with it.

Comment: @Duck Well, in my particular program design requires one thread to do all waiting and then clean things up, and another to manage data streams and signals through poll. Second thread should check on first then child exits, and the easiest way to do this is to wait for SIGCHLD through signalfd, as it is already used for other signals. I considered other ways to go about this, including writing a byte into a pipe, eventfd and sending a realtime signal after wait, but they all add annoying objects or delays.

Comment: @Duck As for "correct data", I meant mainly waitid and any data at all for the signal (although in the beginning I forgot that normal signals are not queued).

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you are doing.  If one thread is doing nothing but sitting blocked in `wait` (in whatever form) poised to process the children why do you need the signal at all?  If you leave the default disposition of SIGCHLD alone the signal will be ignored and the child will be processed by `wait`.  Am I just not understanding your design?

Comment: @Duck The first thread gets its TLS borrowed by nonstadard clone, so it must remain in memory while child processes created by it still run, and waiting in loop is safest and staightforward thing to do it. The other (main) thread does actual work, so it need to know when child exits, and then probally launch another one.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do that. The problem is that you do not know in which thread a signal is delivered (first). On the other hand `sigwaitinfo()` removes the signal from the pending signals set. So the thread calling `waitpid()` may never return.